# Javascript filter was unfair

Tags: javascript, chrome-debugging

I'm trying to get existCount from an array, which has id in selected array.

But something went wrong, I had an item with `id = 5493` but `existCount.length 0`

My JS code:

```
var existCount = $scope.selectedScript.filter(function (item) {
    return item.id === script.script_id;
});
console.log('existCount.length ', existCount.length);
console.log('$scope.selectedScript ', $scope.selectedScript);
console.log('script.script_id ', script.script_id);
```

Chrome Console view:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UVWw.png

// Sorry I forgot the first output line, but this line's at the top of `$scope.selectedScript` and it was `existCount.length = 0`

Where my fault?

How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't post [images of code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). [Edit] your question to format your code as blocks using the `{ }` icon or Ctrl+K.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Ok, I will edit now, thank for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `return item.id === script.script_id;` to `return item.id == script.script_id;`

In your case: **item.id** was a number, **script.script_id** was a string. You can see it in chrome debug by color, black for string, blue for number.

=== is the hard way to compare in JS.

You can see at https://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/8572205

So === return **false** and no item added into **existCount**

Comment: Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

if you use triple-equals `===`, make sure both the values in comparison are of same type. I suspect `script.script_id` is a string.

Try changing `===` to `==`